# How to Get/Read Error Log Information from Android (Not ACRA)

Tags: android, logging, error-handling, livecode

I have an android app that is deployed to .apk file.

I tested my app to the android device and it froze and closed.

I want to know why is that happening even though my app worked on the PC so I think I need something that can report some error logs so that I can debug that problem.

How to do that?

---

I saw some questions similar to this that had an answer and it links to ACRA, I tried to visit the site but it requires eclipse to work it. (If I'm wrong, how to use ACRA?)

Note: I am using livecode in windows to create android apps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the output of `adb logcat`

Not sure what platform you are on so I'll give the OS X, Linux version.

Open up terminal

```
cd /path to android sdk/platform-tools
./adb logcat
```

Now launch your app and do whatever you did to make it crash.

*Note you can also use put statements to include your own logs from live code scripts*

Comment: Where I can find the `adb logcat`?